# Set JSON object root using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

When serializing an object using the  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`, is there a way to set the "root" or top-level key in the JSON string?

For example, here is a class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When it is serialized using...

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    string retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Dispose();
    return retVal;
}
```

The produced JSON string looks like:

```
{"FirstName":"Jane","LastName":"McDoe"}
```

Is there a way to have the serializer prepend some value?

For example:

```
{Person: {"FirstName":"Jane","LastName":"McDoe"}}
```

Of course I could simply change my `Serialize` method to wrap the returned JSON string, e.g.:

```
string retVal = "{Person:" + Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()) + "}";
```

But I was wondering if there was some way to tell the serializer to add it? The `namespace` property on the `DataContract` attribute didn't seem to help.

Comment: Use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), it will seriously make your life *much* easier when working with JSON; I find the .NET offerings out-of-the-box to be very, very lacking.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap it in the type?  What you are proposing does not seem like good JSON to me.  I would just go one step further and just make an array.  {Persons:[Person]}

Comment: Actually I'm working on a CouchDB client.. when you add an object (JSON) via the CouchDB API it wants the object to have a label. I will check out JSON.NET too. Thx

Comment: I also notice that one of the Serialize method signatures asks for a  "XmlDictionaryString rootName" parameter but it doesn't seem to work.. okay onto JSON.NET now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it's not something too pretty - you need to know some of the [JSON to XML mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx) rules which the `DataContractJsonSerializer` uses. For the simple case, where you just want to wrap the object in the type name, it's fairly simple - the code below does that. You need to create the serializer with the "root" name you want (in this case I used the type name), and pass to it a `XmlDictionaryWriter` instance which has been given the root element.

```
public class StackOverflow_7930629
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        public Person() { }
        public Person(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.LastName = lastname;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDictionaryWriter w = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms);
        w.WriteStartElement("root");
        w.WriteAttributeString("type", "object");
        serializer.WriteObject(w, obj);
        w.WriteEndElement();
        w.Flush();
        string retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Dispose();
        return retVal;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Serialize(new Person("Jane", "McDoe")));
    }
}
```

As was mentioned in one of the comments, working with JSON and the `DataContractJsonSerializer` isn't something too friendly. Some JSON-specific libraries such as JSON.NET or the JsonValue types (nuget package JsonValue) can make your life a lot easier.